# why is my linear regression line so short?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, linear-regression

For a student project, I have to plot the knob position rc as a function of the corresponding wavelength in nanometres.
When doing a linear regression, my line is very short. How can I change this? And how could I add error bars?

It looks like this:

[image: It looks like this]

But I want it to look more like this:

[image: desired result]

This is the data:

```
rc      nm
21.22   728.1
13.62   587.6
11.51   504.7
11.36   501.6
11.18   492.2
10.62   471.3
9.94    447.1
8.47    388.9
```

This is my code for a scatter plot:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from scipy import stats


df = pd.read_csv('datalin.csv')

X = df.drop(['rc'], axis=1)
y = df['rc']

df.head()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)

LinearRegression()
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)

plt.scatter(X_train, y_train,color='g')
plt.plot(X_test, y_pred,color='k')

plt.show()
```

I tried using `sklearn.linear_model`, `LinearRegression`.

Comment: What does RC stand for? Rotation... something?

Comment: it's the knob position of the grating (of a Czerny-Turner spectroscope)

Comment: The highest (728) data point looks like an erroneous outlier, because the linear fit is much, much more accurate without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The turqoise (desired) plot doesn't make a tonne of sense, since the scatter points don't add any new information - they're all on the line of regression. Either don't show them at all, or show them as the original (experimental) data.

`sklearn` and `scipy` are not needed as dependencies.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

rc, wavelength = np.array((
    (21.22,  728.1),
    (13.62,  587.6),
    (11.51,  504.7),
    (11.36,  501.6),
    (11.18,  492.2),
    (10.62,  471.3),
    (9.94 ,  447.1),
    (8.47 ,  388.9),
)).T


(m, b), (residual,), rank, (m_sing, b_sing) = np.linalg.lstsq(
    a=np.stack((wavelength, np.ones_like(wavelength)), axis=1),
    b=rc, rcond=None,
)
title = f'rc ~ {m:.5f}λ - {-b:.3f}'
print(title)
rc_approx = m*wavelength + b

fig: plt.Figure
ax: plt.Axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(wavelength, rc, c='#65dbc4')
ax.errorbar(
    wavelength, rc_approx,
    yerr=np.abs(rc - rc_approx),
    c='#65dbc4', capsize=6,
)
ax.set_title(title)
ax.set_xlabel('λ (nm)')
ax.set_ylabel('Knob position r_c (#)')
plt.show()
```

[image: fit]

But really, error bars aren't needed here since there are so few data; and the highest point is clearly an outlier:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

rc, wavelength = np.array((
    (21.22,  728.1),
    (13.62,  587.6),
    (11.51,  504.7),
    (11.36,  501.6),
    (11.18,  492.2),
    (10.62,  471.3),
    (9.94 ,  447.1),
    (8.47 ,  388.9),
)).T


(m, b), (residual,), rank, (m_sing, b_sing) = np.linalg.lstsq(
    a=np.stack((wavelength[1:], np.ones_like(wavelength[1:])), axis=1),
    b=rc[1:],
    rcond=None,
)
title = f'rc ~ {m:.5f}λ - {-b:.3f}'
print(title)
rc_approx = m*wavelength + b

fig: plt.Figure
ax: plt.Axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(wavelength, rc, marker='+')
ax.plot(wavelength, rc_approx)
ax.set_title(title)
ax.set_xlabel('λ (nm)')
ax.set_ylabel('Knob position r_c (#)')
plt.show()
```

[image: better fit]